# Not able to target multiple words with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am trying to add a span element around specific text on a webpage. This will allow me to add tool-tips to certain words with [jQuery's tooltip title attribute](https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/). This function works great for it:

```
<label class="gfield_label">
    Clinicians provide contraception, including single-day LARC insertions, without requiring routine pelvic exams, cervical
    cancer screenings and STI results before offering contraception.
</label>

jQuery('.gfield_label').each(function() {
    var text = jQuery(this).text();
    jQuery(this).html(text.replace("LARC", "<span title='THIS BETTER WORK'>LARC</span>")); 

    $( function() {
        $( document ).tooltip();
    } );
});
```

However, when trying to target multiple keywords in different `<label>` elements it breaks:

```
<label class="gfield_label">
    Clinicians provide contraception, including single-day LARC insertions, without requiring routine pelvic exams, cervical
    cancer screenings and STI results before offering contraception.
</label>

<br />
<br />
<br />
<label class="gfield_label">
    Clinicians provide contraception, including single-day LARC insertions, without requiring routine pelvic exams, cervical
    cancer screenings and STI results before offering contraception.
</label>

jQuery('.gfield_label').each(function() {
    var text = jQuery(this).text();
    jQuery(this).html(text.replace("LARC", "<span title='the tooltip for LARC'>LARC</span>")); 
    jQuery(this).html(text.replace("provide", "<span title='the tooltip for provide'>provide</span>"));
});

$( function() {
    $( document ).tooltip();
} );
```

Any ideas? Here is a [codePen](https://codepen.io/thatemployee/pen/MvXLWZ).

Edit: I am using jQuery to add span elements around HTML words due to the fact I don't have access to the HTML code.

Comment: Your codePen, when I remove the comments.. it seems to do what you ask.   Can you explain in what way it doesn't work?

Comment: @Keith check my answer for the problem that he has there :)

Comment: I think I've spotted the problem, .. I'll post a snippet below..

Comment: @Keith , it has been solved by already (:

Comment: Instead of editing something like *"Solved"* into your answer, accept the answer you find most useful by clicking the check-mark next to it. This will properly mark the question as solved on a system level.

Comment: @BaummitAugen actually he just said he needs to wait a few more minutes to accept the answer. There is a time limit from the time an answer posted and the time you can accept it.

Comment: @Dekel Thanks, I am aware of the limit; they posted that comment less than 30sec before mine, so I hadn't seen it yet. Their edit indicated that educating them about the Accept votes might be a useful thing to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You override the first replace that you do when you use the original `text` to do the second `replace`.

Here is a fix:

```js
jQuery('.gfield_label').each(function() {
    var text = jQuery(this).text();
    text = text.replace("LARC", "<span title='the tooltip for LARC'>LARC</span>")
    text = text.replace("provide", "<span title='the tooltip for provide'>provide</span>")
    jQuery(this).html(text);
});

$( function() {
    $( document ).tooltip();
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" />
<label class="gfield_label">
  Clinicians provide contraception, including single-day LARC insertions, without requiring routine pelvic exams, cervical
cancer screenings and STI results before offering contraception.
</label>

<br />
<br />
<br />
<label class="gfield_label">
  Clinicians provide contraception, including single-day LARC insertions, without requiring routine pelvic exams, cervical
cancer screenings and STI results before offering contraception.
</label>
```

> Note that your code might not work with all keywords, for example - if you will replace the word `LARC` and then you will try to replace the word `span` or `title` or `for` it will also replace the words inside the `<span title='the tooltip for LARC'>` and it will break your html.

Comment: You are welcome. Check the note in my answer, it's **very** important!